# Can't get envelope sender to set correctly, email goes to spam in gmail

Tags: php, email, spam, sender

I'm really stuck. The emails I'm generating have the nobody apache address set for the envelope sender.

Here's my PHP code:

```
$to = $emailresult;
    include 'inc/msg/resetpassword.php';
    if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, '-f' . $from)) {
        echo 'A temporary password has been sent to ' . $emailresult . '. Please check your inbox and logon with your new password';
        } else {
        echo("Message delivery failed...");
        }
```

The file included on line 2

```
<?php
$subject = "XXXClient Dashboard - Password Reset Request Received";
$headers .= "From: XXX Alert <".$from.">\r\n" . "Reply-To: XXXSupport     <support@XXX.com>\r\n" . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\nX-originating-IP: XXX.167.43.105\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$body = $email_header . '
    <h1 style="color: #666666;font-weight: normal;font-size: 18px;text-align: center;padding: 0;margin: 0;">We have recieved a request to reset your password. </h1>
    <p>Hello,
    <br>
    Your new temporary password is <b>' . $passwordresult .
    '</b>. You may logon to the <a style="color:#8A2BE2; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold;" href="'. $site_url . '">XX Client Dashboard</a> with your email address and temporary password, then visit the profile section where you can choose a new password.</p>

' . $email_footer;
?>
```

Here's the email source I'm getting: http://pastebin.com/nbGUaHP1

Works fine to my work email, but when I send to gmail it always goes to spam. I have the -f flag set correctly but it doesn't want to change the envelope sender so I believe that's the problem. Anyone know why the envelope sender won't set with this code?

Comment: don't use mail() or build your own mime emails. mail() is total garbage, and building your own mime is painful. just use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer and make your life a LOT easier.

Answer (score 0):

I was editing the wrong part of my code. I did end up getting it working. Even with the envelope sender and an SPF pass, I am still landing in the gmail spam folder which kind of sucks.